# Mousedown event listener does not fire on cross-origin iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain, content-script

I use `document.addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {...}, true);` in a browser extension's content script on Chrome to listen on the `mousedown` event. When clicking on the username field on `www.icloud.com`, it does not fire while it works on all other websites on which I tested it. I found out that the login form is an iframe loaded from `idmsa.apple.com`.

Is it possible to get the event listener to fire when clicking on a field within a cross-origin iframe or is this not possible due to the same-origin policy?

Comment: Run an additional content script in that iframe, it'll see the event. Declare it with ["all_frames": true](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#frames) and use messaging through background script to coordinate with the main content script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The call `chrome.tabs.executeScript({file:"content.js", allFrames:true});` was surrounded by `if (details.frameId === 0)`. After removing this condition, I noticed that the permission `tabs` was missing in the `manifest.json` due to an error message in the log. Seems that the permission `activeTab` sufficies for injecting a content script into top frames, but for sub frames `tabs` is necessary.